# Script that keep reading a stream

Tags: bash

Sometimes I `cat` a stream like `/dev/input/event0`.

I want to write a script that does something every time there is more output.

The definition of more output might be every time it reads a byte.

How can that be done? is there some command that does it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a shell script you will be limited to complete lines.  You'll need to use C/Perl/Python/whatever for finer grained reading.

```
while read line; do
  # do something based on content of $line; remember to quote it
done </dev/input/event0
```

Comment: Many shells support reading less than a line, it is just not standard. *ksh* can read (e.g.) five bytes with `read -N5`, *bash* can read five (possibly multibyte) characters with `read -rN5`, *zsh* can read 5 (possibly multibyte) characters with `read -u0 -k5`. Both *bash* and *zsh* can read bytes instead of characters by using the C locale (or probably any 8-bit character ctype).

Comment: @Chris Consider writing up an answer!

Comment: Apparently `read -N` is new in bash 4.2, so it may not be everywhere. Also, *bash* `LC_CTYPE=C IFS= read -rN 1` seems to eat certain bytes (0x00, 0xff). *ksh* seems to eat 0x00 (probably due to using NUL terminated strings internally). *zsh* seems to work correctly though.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on geekosaur's answer:
You might want to try `read -n 1 byte` to read one byte at a time, then do something with `$byte`.

EDIT:

Just tried this as I had never used that command before (just looked up `info bash`), but it seems to munch all white space and line endings. I don't have an explanation for this yet.

Try the following scripts to fine tune command arguments:

```
(for j in $(seq 1 10); do for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo -n "$i, "; sleep .02; done; echo "& $j."; done) | (while read line; do echo $line; done)

(for j in $(seq 1 10); do for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo -n "$i, "; sleep .05; done; echo "& $j."; done) | (while read -n 1 byte; do echo -n "$byte"; done)
```

So unfortunately this does not give the expected result.

EDIT (with Chris' help):

```
(for j in $(seq 1 10); do for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo -n "$i, "; sleep .02; done; echo "& $j."; done) | (while IFS= read -N 1 byte; do echo -n "$byte"; done)
```

This gives exactly the expected result.
Note: whether I use `-n`, `-N`, or `-rN` does not change the result, it's all good (with text, I did not test the limitation that Chris talks about: 0x00 and 0xff).

Comment: That "munching" is why I said "remember to quote it"; if you say `echo $foo`, `$foo` will get all whitespace (all characters in `$IFS`, to be pedantic) compacted to single spaces, whereas `echo "$foo"` will preserve them.  But you have to use it *consistently* to make sure the whitespace is always quoted.

Comment: @geekosaur, it is not a quoting problem, it is due to the fact that *bash* seems to ignore IFS members in `read -n` (and `read -N` in 4.2). The workaround is to use `IFS= read -rn 1` (even then, *bash* still eats 0x00 and 0xff).

Comment: This would be why I don't use `bash`; it always seems to have stupid bugs like that.  (My "favorite" `bash` bug was in some 2.x version where backslashes in case patterns didn't stop `*` from being a glob match.)